# REST API for global SRTM in .hgt format

Tags: dem, srtm

I have been searching on internet for a quite a while and all the sites I found only gave on-site download option (like USGS [EarthExplorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/)), no APIs. Is there any free or paid rest API for accessing 1 arc-second SRTM DEM in .hgt format? And if there are no APIs available what other options do I have?

Comment: Just to understand: you want to retrieve the .hgt data or just the file names?

Comment: I want to retrieve .hgt data. I already know how to retrieve filenames for particular location.

Comment: Why would someone host such data?  What's in it for them?  There's a non-trivial bit of work to download and prep the data, but it is free, so your option would be to load what you need, and then consume it.

Comment: @Vince so do i need to make my own server (with all the data i need loaded on it) and APIs?

Comment: You need to inventory dsta sources, inventory server options (including writing your own from scratch), matrix the sources with servers, select a combination, obtain the data, install (or write and install) the server, load the data, and serve it. Each one of these tasks is *too broad* (or *opinion-based*) for GIS SE.

Comment: Thats alot of work, is there any easy solution? I just need the dem data (it could be anywhere in the world)

Comment: Mapzen saved my life here is the [link](https://mapzen.com/documentation/terrain-tiles/formats/#skadi)